# plotting vertical bars instead of points, plot_date

Tags: python, date, matplotlib

I want to plot vertical bars instead of points.  The actual data I have are irregularly spaced, so this will help visualize gaps more easily.
When I try to plot it, the best I can do are points, which don't increase in size as you zoom in!

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import datetime

XX = [datetime.date.today()+datetime.timedelta(x) for x in range(10)]
YY = range(10)
plt.plot_date(XX,YY,'o')
```

[image]

[image]

Any ideas on how I can make taller/bigger (but not wider!) points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ax.vlines`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.vlines) to plot a collection of vertical lines.

You can adjust `ymin` and `ymax` to suit your data.

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import datetime

XX = [datetime.date.today()+datetime.timedelta(x) for x in range(10)]

plt.vlines(XX, ymin=0, ymax=1, linewidth=5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean bars like this?

[image]

And here is the code:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import datetime

XX = [datetime.date.today()+datetime.timedelta(x) for x in range(10)]
YY = range(10)

plt.plot_date(XX,YY,'|')
plt.show()
```

You can change the shape of your plot by changing the third argument you pass in the plt.plot_date function. 
In your code you are passing an 'o' that is why you get a dot. Here i pass bar to plot bar.